# Tool to export an entire JIRA project in a readable text format quickly

Tags: export, jira

I am the lead developer on a project for a 'difficult' client. I will try not to bore anybody with the details but here is my issue I am facing.

Our client has a team of QA testers that are managing their project through JIRA. We currently have a fixed bid contract with them to supply them the software they requested at a fixed price and any additional features or pre-existing issues will be covered under time and materials.
They have taken the time to raise every defect within the system unrelated to the current fixed bid process and have tried to get them resolved for free and each time we have come to an agreement through JIRA comments that this is a preexisting issue/new feature and you will have to pay for it after the project has been completed which they have agreed to.

The issue is this client has a history of forgetting conversations and email trains that don't benefit them putting a lot of wasted time on our side digging up proof we agreed to handle a situation a specific way.

The project will not complete for several more weeks but as soon as it does I will likely be removed from the JIRA project by their administrator and they will begin asking again for us to complete all this additional work at no cost and I will lose access to the comments on each issue explaining to them it will not be free and them agreeing.

I am currently exporting each ticket after it closes but this is wasting about 30-40 minutes a day and would be interested if there is a tool out there that can export an entire JIRA project to a readable text format that I can run once near the project end.

**TL:DR; Is there a tool that will allow me to export an entire JIRA project in a text readable format before I lose access to the project and all information included within that project**

Comment: The [help/on-topic] specifically says that questions asking us to find or recommend a tool are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export as CSV doesn't include comments and is limited to 1000 issues be default.
I have used the jira-python library to retrieve all issues, all fields, all comments from a single project. Missed the attachments though.

But what you have is a people problem more than a technical problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Large exports (e.g. many hundreds of issues) are not recommended.
To change the number of issues that are exported, change the value of the tempMax parameter in the URL.
To export search results to Microsoft Excel:
Choose Issues > Search for Issues.
Refine your search, as described in Searching for Issues, then choose the Export menu.
Choose one of the following from the dropdown menu:
'Excel (All fields)'— this will create a spreadsheet column for every issue field (excluding comments).
Note: This will only show the custom fields that are available for all of the issues in the search results. For example, if a field is only available for one project and multiple projects are in the search results then that field will not appear in the Excel document. The same goes for fields that are only available for certain issue types.
'Excel (Current fields)' — this will create a spreadsheet column for the issue fields that are currently displayed in your Issue Navigator.
A file called  - .xls will be created. Edit this file using Microsoft Excel and/or save it as required.